# Filter on nested property

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I have the following models:

```
public class Blog
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public List<Post> Posts { get; set; }
}

public class Post 
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int BlogId { get; set; }
    public Blog Blog { get; set; }
}
```

I have an IQueryable like:

```
var results = Blog.Include(x => x.Posts);
```

Everything works great until I want to filter on a property of the Post class. I need something like this:

```
var filteredResults = results.Where(x => x.Posts.Where(y => y.Description == "Test"));
```

This works If I append Any() to the second .Where(). This would not be right though because I only want to return the matching Posts, not all.
Any suggestions on how to approach this?

Comment: I think you're actually looking for [SelectMany()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.selectmany?view=netcore-3.1) which will flatten the list for you, then you can just have a single `Where()` to test the description.

Comment: @itsme86 Replacing the first Where() with SelectMany() turns it into an IQueryable of Post but I need an IQueryable of Blog.

Comment: In your question you state that you want to return the matching Posts. If I understand you correctly then, you want to return Blogs and have each Blog only contain "Test" Posts. In that case, you'll need to actually create new Blog objects that only contain the Posts you want.

Comment: @itsme86 `SelectMany` is translated to sql?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Entities don't filter like this. A Blog entity will, and should refer to *ALL* Posts it is associated with. EF can apply global filters to data to accommodate things like soft-delete (IsActive) or tenancy (ClientId) scenarios, but not filtered children like this.

This is a view/consumer concern, not a domain one so you should be looking to separate those concerns using Projection to return the data you want:

```
string postFilter = "Test";

var filteredResults = context.Blogs
    .Where(x => x.Posts.Any(p => p.Description == postFilter))
    .Select(x => new BlogViewModel
    {
        BlogId = x.BlogId,
        Title = x.Title,
        FilteredPosts = x.Posts.Where(p => p.Description == postFilter)
            .Select(p => new PostViewModel
            {
               PostId = p.PostId,
               Description = p.Description,
               Text = p.Text,
               // ...
           {).ToList()
    }).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

You could approach this from bottom up.

```
var blogIds = Posts.Where(x => x.Description == "Test").Select(x => x.BlogId);
var result = Blog.Where(x => blogIds.Contains(x.Id))
```

Note that you might want to do:

```
x => x.Description.Contains("Test")
```

instead of:

```
x => x.Description == "Test"
```

in first query

You'll still have to map corresponding posts to each blog though

**Update**

Steve's answer is correct. I'll just add that it may translate in a lot of nested select queries. You can check the output in SQL Server profiler, or in the output window in Visual Sudio. So here's everything including mapping:

```
var posts = Posts.Where(x => x.Description == "test").ToList();
var blogIds = posts.Select(x => x.BlogId).ToList();
var blogs = Blog.Where(x => blogIds.Contains(x.Id)).ToList();

foreach(var blog in blogs)
    blog.Posts = posts.Where(x => x.BlogId == x.Id).ToList()
```